# Changing python version in ROS

Tags: ros, python, opencv, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How to change the Python version in ROS, I installed EPD (Enthought Python Distribution) and it seems my ROS has used this version, instead of Python 2.7 which is installed by default ... I want to use OpenCV but it sends me an error 'ImportError: No module named cv', i tried that in the Python IDLE 2.7 and it sends me no error, how can i change the version? Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31854/changing-python-version-in-ros/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2012-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems more like a question for the EPD community than the ROS community.  You need to configure your EPD to use Python libraries distributed with ROS.  All of these are locatable using the PYTHONPATH configuration with ROS, plus the default site/dist-packages location that normal Python uses.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3